# Cookie hook not work in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie'

const CookiesHelp = () => {
    const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['token'])

    const setToTrue = () => {
        setCookie('token', 'true')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <label>{cookies.token}</label>
            <button onClick={setToTrue}>Set true</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default CookiesHelp
```

And when I run my app, I have an error:

**react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.**

I use hook in functional component. Why this error has occured?

Using CookiesHelp:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { forecasts: [], loading: true }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateWeatherData()
    }

    static renderForecastsTable(forecasts) {
        return (
            <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                        <th>Summary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {forecasts.map(forecast =>
                        <tr key={forecast.date}>
                            <td>{forecast.date}</td>
                            <td>{forecast.temperatureC}</td>
                            <td>{forecast.temperatureF}</td>
                            <td>{forecast.summary}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading... Please refresh once the ASP.NET backend has started. See <a href="https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact">https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact</a> for more details.</em></p>
            : App.renderForecastsTable(this.state.forecasts);

        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <h1 id="tabelLabel">Weather forecast</h1>
                    <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                    {contents}
                </div>
                <UploadPicture />
                <CookiesHelp />
            </>
        );
    }

    async populateWeatherData() {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7054/WeatherForecast');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

Default Visual Studio ReactJS + WebAPI template. *useState* in CookiesHelp don't throw an exception.

```
root.render(
    <CookiesProvider>
        <App />
    </CookiesProvider>
);
```

May be I need use *useCookies* in App.js?

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) (it even says so in the error message you quoted!). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: Probably you are *calling* the function in a way that doesn't treat it as a component, but one of the other possibilities listed in the error might be the case. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The way you're *using* `CookiesHelp` is vital information for the question.

Comment: Update question

Comment: I have exactly the same problem pedro. How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, setCookie wasn't working even when being called in functional component.
I solved this by reinstalling react-cookie in the correct place, turns out my react-app had node_modules installed in two different levels and was causing React module to be undefined inside react-cookie code.

```
app
 |node_modules     <-- where packages should be
 |package.json
node_modules
package.json       <-- deleted those and reinstalled in app
```